# Can't change brightness on element via JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a brightness controller on my website. So my idea is to add css `filter:brightness()` on the element by using JavaScript. I've succesfully accessed the brighness value in my script.

What the problem is that I can't increase/decrease the value.

Please take a look at the JavaScript.

```js
const theWrapper = document.querySelector('.post-wrapper')

function brightness(type) {
  let nowBrg = window.getComputedStyle(theWrapper, null).getPropertyValue("filter");
  var numBrg = nowBrg.match(/\d+/g) * 100;
console.log(numBrg);
  if(type == "up") {
theWrapper.style.filter = `brightness(${numBrg + 10}%)`;
}else if(type == "down") {
theWrapper.style.filter = `brightness(${numBrg - 10}%)`;
}
  document.getElementById('bright').innerHTML = numBrg;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-wrapper" style="filter: brightness(100%);">
<div class="wrapper" id="content">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis accusamus debitis possimus magni, ab explicabo laboriosam nesciunt quisquam expedita consequatur ut deserunt suscipit, voluptatibus, excepturi maiores quasi modi similique ad.
    </p>

    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis accusamus debitis possimus magni, ab explicabo laboriosam nesciunt quisquam expedita consequatur ut deserunt suscipit, voluptatibus, excepturi maiores quasi modi similique ad.
    </p>

    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis accusamus debitis possimus magni, ab explicabo laboriosam nesciunt quisquam expedita consequatur ut deserunt suscipit, voluptatibus, excepturi maiores quasi modi similique ad.
    </p>
</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper-fontsize">
<div class="brightness">
<h4>Brightness</h4>
<button onclick="brightness('up')">+</button>
<span id="bright">1</span>
<button onclick="brightness('down')">-</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: see [this](https://jsfiddle.net/LercDsgn/bdqswnax/28/) fiddle that I made. I couldn't get it to perfectly work, but the code may give you some idea. Not that I'm a professional, just see a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

First, your regex returns an array instead of a number.

Secondly, it is difficult to notice the change in brightness for a block with a completely transparent background.

```js
const theWrapper = document.querySelector(".post-wrapper");

function brightness(type = null) {
  let nowBrg = window.getComputedStyle(theWrapper).filter;
  let numBrg = Math.round(nowBrg.match(/(\d+(\.\d+)?)/g) * 100);

  if (type) {
    if (type == "up" && numBrg < 1000) { numBrg += 10; }
    if (type == "down" && numBrg > 0) { numBrg -= 10; }
  }
  theWrapper.style.filter = `brightness(${numBrg}%)`;
  document.getElementById("bright").innerHTML = numBrg;
}

brightness();
```

```html
<div class="post-wrapper" style="filter: brightness(40%); background-color: #fff;">
  <div class="wrapper" id="content">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis accusamus debitis possimus magni, ab explicabo laboriosam nesciunt quisquam expedita consequatur ut deserunt suscipit, voluptatibus, excepturi maiores quasi modi similique ad.
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis accusamus debitis possimus magni, ab explicabo laboriosam nesciunt quisquam expedita consequatur ut deserunt suscipit, voluptatibus, excepturi maiores quasi modi similique ad.
    </p>

    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis accusamus debitis possimus magni, ab explicabo laboriosam nesciunt quisquam expedita consequatur ut deserunt suscipit, voluptatibus, excepturi maiores quasi modi similique ad.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper-fontsize">
  <div class="brightness">
    <h4>Brightness</h4>
    <button onclick="brightness('down')">&minus;</button>
    <span id="bright">1</span>
    <button onclick="brightness('up')">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```